# Use Node to copy an sftp file in place

Tags: node.js, sftp

Short of manually creating a read/write stream and effectively doing the copy code myself, is there an easy way to copy a file in an sftp folder using Node? I've checked 3rd party libraries and there are lots of easy ways to copy a local file to an sftp site. But what I have in mind is connect to the sftp, then ideally use a library to issue a simple command like "copy file A and rename it to B", without having to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called ssh2. I think this is what you need.

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Read docs there is a lot of examples.

Example how to get directory list

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
```

`var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    sftp.readdir('foo', function(err, list) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.dir(list);
      conn.end();
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 22,
  username: 'frylock',
  password: 'nodejsrules'
});`

Also take a look at methods `fastPut` and `fastGet`

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md#sftpstream-static-constants

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mykola. But fastPut and fastGet actually download and upload files. I need something that can easily copy the file in place at the sftp server without ever involving my local file structure. I've looked at ssh and don't really see anything in there that fits the bill short of manually setting up a read/write stream to open a file in place, copy the data, then write it to a new file. Presumably any copy function would just do that anyway. I'm just lazy and looking for a library that hides the dirty work behind a simple "copy" API call :-)

Comment: You can run shel commands with it too..So just check docs and youll see. You can do something like rm -rf someDir or cp some files to other place. Or whatever

Comment: Like this client.exec('cd ' + config.projectPath + ' && git status' + ' && git branch' + ' && git checkout ', function(err,stream){})

Comment: Right, but the file I want to copy is not in a local directory, it's on the sftp server.

Comment: @AB  Did you find any solution?